# Blank page shown during the navigation in ionic framework based mobile app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-cli

This is my first experience in ionic framework based mobile app.my problem is a white blank page show in testing my app in android device.but it worked fine in browser.The workflow of my app is first login,then it redirect to homepage.homepage contain some icons for my service.after clicking each service it redirect to detail page.when redirect to detail page not showing my content only white blank page will display.some times this error is not showing.And another problem is after register it redirect to home page again the same issue occur.i cant understand how this happen.and browser console not showing any error.MY index.html and app.js is given below.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$ionicConfigProvider) {
  $ionicConfigProvider.backButton.text('').previousTitleText('');
  $stateProvider
 .state('app', {
   url: "/app",
   abstract: true,
   templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
   controller: 'AppCtrl'
 })
 .state('app.detail', {
     url: "/detail",
     views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/detail.html",
        controller: 'DetailCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
   .state('app.contact', {
    url: "/contact",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/contact.html"
      }
    }
  })
   .state('app.payment', {
    url: "/payment",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/payment.html"
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.cart_detail', {
    url: "/cart_detail",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/cart_detail.html"
      }
    }
  })
   .state('app.about', {
    url: "/about",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/about.html"
      }
    }
  })
  .state('slide', {
    url: "/slide",
    templateUrl: "templates/slide.html"
  })
   .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'

    })
 .state('register', {
      url: '/register',
      templateUrl: 'templates/register.html',
      controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
    })

//start r@khi

 .state('app.paymentnotification', {
    url: "/paymentnotification",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/paymentnotification.html",
             controller: 'PaymentCtrl'  
            }
    }
  })

  .state('verification', {
    url: "/verification",
 views: {
      '': {
    templateUrl: "templates/verification.html",
        controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
}
}
  })

 .state('paymentsecurity', {
    url: "/paymentsecurity",
    templateUrl: "templates/paymentsecurity.html",
        controller: 'OrderpaymentCtrl'


  })


    .state('app.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
          controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
});
```

My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->


    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="lib/ion-datetime-picker/release/ion-datetime-picker.min.js"></script>
    <link href="lib/ion-datetime-picker/release/ion-datetime-picker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/File.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="plugins/org.apache.cordova.file-transfer/www/FileTransfer.js"></script>
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/config.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!--<script src="https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script> -->
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loginCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/registerCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slideCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/detailCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/homeCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/verificationCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/paymentCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/orderpaymentCtrl.js"></script>



</head>

<body ng-app="testapp">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you check your console in developers tools? Any error ?

Comment: Yes.but no error in console.

Comment: On which pages you are facing this problem ? Verification ?

Comment: no detail.html page

Comment: i have some icons in my home page.clicking to my icon <a ng-click="a_service({{services[$index].ser_id}})"><img ng-src="{{services[$index].ser_logo}}" width="70%"></a>

Comment: a_service scope function in HomeCtrl.from this function i use $state.go('app.detail'); this to go detail page.but some time nothing to shown in detail page.only blank white page.in browser work perfectly.problem in mobile device.

Comment: Do you have whitelist plugin installed ? and also try changing <ion-nav-view> to <ui-view> ? Let me know

Comment: white list plugin already installed.now i am trying to give <ion-nav-view> to <ui-view>

Comment: <ui-view > is not working.again white page without my content.

Comment: direct login no problem.after registering redirect to homepage.then click to icon detail page shows white blank page.

Comment: you are stuck with WSOD(white screen of death) of ionic framework, There are lots of reason for this to happen. Lets use timeout like this  $timeout(function() {
    $state.go('app.detail');
}, 5000);

Comment: also make sure you have < allow-navigation href="*" /> this in your config.xml .. maybe CSP is the reason (y)

Comment: < allow-navigation href="*" /> already given in config.xml

Comment: now i  am trying to give

 $timeout(function() { $state.go('app.detail'); }, 5000); instead of $state.go('app.detail'); but not redirect to detail page.

Comment: Now it is working.thanks for your reply.

Comment: i  gave $timeout(function() { $state.go('app.detail'); }, 5000); then is working.is any other solution for this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124704/discussion-between-albert-and-ujjwal-kaushik).

Answer (score 0):

use 
ionic run android --livereload --consolelogs
it will show detailed   console outputs or problem that cause white screen.
anyway there is a post on ionic blog that describes more about app debugging 
http://blog.ionic.io/angularjs-console/